# Capturar Scroll de PDF dentro de um embed

Tags: jquery, html5

Opa, 
Tenho que manipular o scroll de um documento PDF, dentro de uma tag EMBED. 
Seria da seguinte forma, ao abrir o documento, o botão de ACEITAR, ficaria desabilitado e somente quando o usuário, rolasse o documento 100% o botão seria liberado. 
Porém, não estou conseguindo esse resultado final. 
Segue os códigos abaixo, que estou utilizando.

```
 <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
    aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel" style="color:black;">Termos e condições</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" style="color:black;">
          <div>

            <embed class="frame-termo" id="termo"
              src="https:soulpay.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/Contrato-de-Adesao-e-Credenciamento-SoulPay-alteracoes-novembro18-merged.pdf"
              type="application/pdf"/>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btn-fechar" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
          <button id="botaoAceitar" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Accept" data-dismiss="modal"
            disabled>Aceitar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Abaixo segue o script que estou utilizando.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(function ($) {
       $('#termo').on('scroll', function () {
         if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
           $('#botaoAceitar').removeAttr('disabled');
         }
       })
     });
  </script>
```

Comment: Não tem como pq não se tem acesso ao embed. Uma solução seria utilizar algum plugin de PDF, que pode dar acesso às propriedades de scroll, ou converter o pdf em imagem.

Comment: e um IFRAME? existe a possibilidade de ter acesso a um IFRAME?

Comment: Se colocar o pdf direto tb não dá, porque o navegador cria um embed.

Comment: O navegador foi feito para exibir HTML... quando vc coloca um PDF nele, ele cria uma tag embed automaticamente.